# VBA to Copy and Paste values to same row in same sheet based on a Trigger

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to VBA and I'm hoping I could get some help here to achieve what I'm trying to do. I've searched and read through, and a lot of solution are about copy and pasting from one sheet to another.

Basically, I want to Copy and Paste the Values in the same row range based on a trigger from another column in the same Sheet.

I've **Column G** with the trigger word, which is "Hired";
I've data range **J5:AG436**
For example, if **G11** is *"Hired"*, I want the existing data in **J11:AG11** to be copied and pasted as Values.

Here's a code that I'm trying to but got nowhere with it. Perhaps this is not it?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim triggerColumn As Long
    triggerColumn = 7 ' column G is the trigger column
    Dim triggerWord As String
    triggerWord = "Hired" ' the trigger word to look for
    
    'define range to which the code will be applied
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = Me.Range("J11:AG436") 'change to match the range of your data
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, dataRange) Is Nothing Then
        ' a cell within the data range was changed
        If Target.Column = triggerColumn Then
            ' the trigger column was changed
            If InStr(1, Target.Value, triggerWord, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                ' the trigger word was found in the changed cell
                ' copy and paste special values from the current cell
                Target.Copy
                Target.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub`
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as an update for anyone looking for this solution, I've asked on MrExcel and got it sorted out. Here's the code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   
    Dim Warning As String
   
    If Intersect(Target, Columns(7)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
   
    Warning = MsgBox("Be warned that the action you are about to take is irreversible. To continue, click OK.", vbCritical + vbOKCancel, "WARNING")
          If Warning = vbOK Then
                trow = Target.Row
                If Target.Value = "Hired" Then
                     With Me.Range(Cells(trow, "J"), Cells(trow, "AG"))
                            .Value = .Value
                     End With
                     Else: Exit Sub
                End If
          End If
         
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Cheers!